# How to display a complex number in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, complex-numbers

I'm programming a GUI in Qt that works with complex numbers. 
While searching in another forums, I saw that I have to use the standard namespace : `using namespace std;`

But when I try to display a complex number, I get errors. I want to put them in QDoubleSpinboxes and then display them. But it doesn't work. 
I tried this :

```
QFormLayout *solutionEcritureComplexe = new QFormLayout;
QDoubleSpinBox *solutionComplexeA = new QDoubleSpinBox;
solutionComplexeA -> setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons);
complex<double> L1 = (0,23);
solutionComplexeA -> setValue(R1);
solutionEcritureComplexe -> addRow("Za = " , solutionComplexeA);
```

I get this error message :

```
> C:\Users\mrali\Documents\Projets Qt\GUI_Etech\FenPrincipale.cpp:238: erreur : no matching function for call to
'QDoubleSpinBox::setValue(std::complex<double>&)'
         solutionComplexeA -> setValue(L1);

                                     ^
```

Please help me, I really want to finish with that project.

Comment: Just a typo, it should be `solutionComplexeA -> setValue(L1);`. For your question, `QDoubleSpinBox->setValue` has input is `double`, but the `complex<double>` is a pair of double.

Comment: You'd need two spinboxes and let them display a component each.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld yes it can be a good option but how should I do if I want to display numbers like " 10+5i " ?

Comment: There's no ready-made widget for that I know of (definitely not in Qt itself). A spinbox also doesn't make that much sense here (what would up/down do? Modify the real or the i value?). One could think of using a QLineEdit with a custom QValidator.